# Regex issue with version of Chrome

Tags: javascript

I want to get a string from an picture's url with regular expression using match() in javascript. I have tested it on a Chrome version 62 and it works great, but in a lower version (e.g. 58) it doesn't work! This is my two lines of code where the issue comes from :

```
// cloneURL = "/assets/images/bonhommeneige.png"
var cloneName = cloneURL.match('(?<=images/)(.*?)(?=.png)');
```

On my Chrome v. 62 it gives me "bonhommeneige" but in Chrome v. 58 I have an error : Invalid regular expression. What is wrong with my regular expression?

Comment: Positive lookbehind is not supported in chrome v58. Change your regexp, you can do it without lookbehind anyway. `(?:images/)(.*?)(?=.png)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Positive lookbehind is not supported in chrome v58. Change your regexp, you can do it without lookbehind anyway. For example you could use non capturing group instead `(?:images/)`:

```js
var cloneURL = "/assets/images/bonhommeneige.png"
var cloneName = cloneURL.match('(?:images/)(.*?)(?=.png)');

console.log(cloneName);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the image name, you can try using the following method:

```js
// Method 1

let cloneUrl  = "/assets/images/bonhommeneige.png";
let imageName = cloneUrl.substring (
  cloneUrl.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,
  cloneUrl.lastIndexOf(".")
);

console.log(imageName);

// Method 2

let matches = cloneUrl.match(/(?:images\/)(\S+)(?:\.png)/);

console.log(matches); // Get the [1] index
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the value between the last `/` and last `.` (and don't forget to escape `.` with `\.`) :

```js
cloneURL = "/assets/images/bonhommeneige.png"

console.log( cloneURL.match(/[^/]+(?=\.)/)[0] )

console.log( cloneURL.match(/([^/]+)\./)[1] )
```